# How to Intercept touch events in nested RecyclerViews to avoid propagation to parent?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, swipe, touch-event

I have a complex layout made of a ViewPager with 3 (horizontal) fragments [PAGE].

Each PAGE is made of several (vertical) RecyclerView [CARD].

Each CARD, has a an (horizontal) RecyclerView with several items.

My problem is that, when swiping between the items, the touch event is ofter propagated to the viewPager, resulting in an unwanted page change.

Is there a way to block, when touching a specific area of the screen (i.e. All the area covered by the most inner RecyclerView) the propagation of the touch event, EVEN if no element  is touched (there is free space bewteen items, and touching there cause the unwanted page change)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vfAI.jpg

Here there is my example, when swiping on the Scrollable Area, I do not want to be able to move to other pages.

Thanks for the help

[Example of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vfAI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If your CARD has a custom RecyclerView (for the horizontal recycler), you could call [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)) on touch events.

This would have the parent RecyclerView as well as the ViewPager stop receiving inputs until the horizontal Recycler stops receiving touch events (the call cleans up itself if I remember right).

Comment: In my case this is what works perfectly inside custom view onTouchEvent